# Mac terminal how can i search in all folders and subfolders for image

Tags: macos, terminal, copy

How can i search for example all .png files on an external disk and copy them to another directory?
Have tried to use the cp command. Have try it but don't work for me
?

Monterey 2.2.1

```
cp /Volumes/Data  *.png /Volumes/Data/pictures_png
```

Answer (score 1):

`cp` command won't work if you need to recursively copy from the sub directories. You need to use `find`.

Syntax:

```
find $SOURCE -type f -name '*.type' -exec cp '{}' $DESTINATION ';'
```

In your case,

```
find  /Volumes/Data -type f -name '*.png' -exec cp '{}' /Volumes/Data/pictures_png ';'
```

Here is how it works:

- `-type f` means copy only files not directories.
- `-name` is to provide the filename to find. Here `*.png` for pattern matching
- `-exec` executes the following line for each result the above find returns.
- `{}` will be replaced with the results from find
- `;` terminates `-exec` command